# batch file to strip numbers from filename and pad to two digits

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-command-prompt

I have a text file with a list of server names (servers.txt) that looks something like this:

server1
server2
server3

I have a feeling this can be done with the FOR command as I use that to perform an action on each name in the file, but I'm not quite sure how to use the delimiters to accomplish this.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in (servers.txt) do (  
  SET machinenum = <magic here>
  ECHO %machinenum%
)
```

expected output

01
02
03

Comment: You might wish to add that this is for a Windows machine.  Using Linux/UNIX shell scripting this would be quite easy.

Comment: +1 no comment for down vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you would do it in your example. Make the token larger (1-8) for however many servers you have. If you don't know how many servers you'll have, it would be a lot easier to put each server on it's own line.

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=server" %%a in ('type server.txt') do set machinenum=0%%a0%%b0%%c
echo %machinenum%
```

If this is an actual batch file, use the double %%. If it's from the command line, use a single %

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set **ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION** to make this work.

The padding with a zero is hard.  You might try:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@echo off
    for %%a in (00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09) do (
    set machinenum=
        @set machinenum=%%a
        @echo !machinenum!
        )
```

If the zero is not necessary, you get some flexibility (assuming 20 servers):

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@echo off
    for /l %%a in (1,1,20) do (
    set machinenum=
        @set machinenum=%%a
        @echo !machinenum!
        )
```